# Dynamically determine the correct type of data with a type hint

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to interpret data differently based on a 'type-field'?

I am loading data (all from the same file). I know the type of the data, and what the type definitions look like. With the current union approach, it'd always show all fields, but I'd like to be able to automatically be able to determine which type applies. I could cast the type during runtime, but that's not ideal.

Not sure if I am pushing TS a bit too much here, and if it instead should live in the actual loading/parsing logic?

Current approach

```js
enum MyTypes {
  TypeA = "A",
  TypeB = "B",
}
```

```js
type IData = {
  type: MyTypes;
  data: IDataAllTypes <---- force the type to be `IDataTypeA` if the type field is `TypeA`
}
```

```js
type IDataAllTypes = IDataTypeA | IDataTypeB

type IDataTypeA = {
  id: string
  age: number
  foo: string[]
}

type IDataTypeB = {
  id: string
  name: string
  bar: string[]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a discriminated union. It's a union type where all members have a common field that can be used to enforce the rest of the type.

You can declare `IData` like this:

```
type IDataA = {
    type: MyTypes.TypeA,
    data: IDataTypeA
}

type IDataB = {
    type: MyTypes.TypeB,
    data: IDataTypeB
}
type IData = IDataA | IDataB
```

Now this works like you expect:

```
const testA: IData = { type: MyTypes.TypeA, data: { id: 'qwe', age: 123, foo: ['a'] }}
const testB: IData = { type: MyTypes.TypeB, data: { id: 'qwe', name: 'asd', bar: ['b'] }}

// Type error. Can't pair type A with values from type B
const testFail: IData = { type: MyTypes.TypeA, data: { id: 'qwe', name: 'asd', bar: ['b'] }}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&ssl=34&ssc=93&pln=30&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2AZygbwFBSk1AQSgF4oAiQ8gGl3xWACFSLGbsBfbbAFwagCSAEQCGPEQWDEyOPAEsAJgC4oaHgCc5IAOZ0R24CvAQARsHV0AZgHtrKtZp0BtALqdufVINHjJzGXSK9hpaunggIhCGqiE6dCYi6sGO2q7uvPzCYiLSWHR4ntHwkmgAdJKEtHh4CtkqWb4MhOmF3tn+edVQhSrFDGV+VdW14vU+EgyM7q0NIiyzxAA+beJT3ADG1iBq3eg8hGPZLJjdDL2I-eVN1FAjIionQVAA5ACOAO7Azzf60QCMACYAMw3Gx2KBOZ4iZ4uKAcLibbY8XZqRiHcTHU6oc4lK6oRg3O4PKBPN6fb5QCJRFRQtAKCkJJIQ54mGFwrjYAD0nPoXnM6ms6lKUAAwiIQM9kcgRHJ1FjgFBiO85DwABZQABuIgANmB0FBLALoK0poidjw9gAxGXa9FzGTynGXCqEupYEnKF4fL43KnRWn0m6MlSQ1mw+FAA)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for - thank you. Maybe relevant to add that I had to add if-based type assertations in order for the IDE to pick up the right data type and associated fields

Comment: Well yeah, this is just on the type side. You use [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) via `if (myData.type === MyTypes.TypeA)` to check if you have one type or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
enum MyTypes {
  TypeA = "A",
  TypeB = "B",
}

type IDataTypeA = {
  id: string
  age: number
  foo: string[]
}

type IDataTypeB = {
  id: string
  name: string
  bar: string[]
}

IDataA {
  type: MyTypes.TypeA,
  data: IDataTypeA,
}

IDataB {
  type: MyTypes.TypeB,
  data: IDataTypeB,
}

IDataAllTypes = IDataA | IDataB;
```